# How do I add icons from Fontello to Datatables sorting?

Tags: datatables, fontello

I use Fontello in my web app along with jQuery DataTables. How do I use the up and down arrows from Fontello to represent the asc/desc sort order in the table header cells?

Answer (score 0):

I mananged to do this using jQuery and the dataTable-specific `drawCallback` function:

```
drawCallback: function( settings ) {
        $(".dataTable thead tr th span.icon-up-open").remove();
        $(".dataTable thead tr th span.icon-down-open").remove();
        $(".dataTable thead tr th.sorting_desc").append("<span class='pull-right icon-up-open'></span");
        $(".dataTable thead tr th.sorting_asc").append("<span class='pull-right icon-down-open'></span");
    }
```